# Share Timestamp within Jenkins

Tags: maven, ant, jenkins

I do have a jenkins job where I execute command from within Maven plugin which executes ant build script. The job also does 2 ant calls as there are 2 mirror servers. Something like this:

```
usr/bin/ant -v -d -f /utils_repo/build.xml ${target} -propertyfile /tmp/myjob/install.properties
```

Where Maven connects to each server and executes something similar.
My question is how can I share timestamp of when jenkins job starts within 2 instances of ant calls. In my ant job I have a backup build step before rolling in a new code, but I need to put the logic if dump/backup was done on the first host, do not do it on the second one as they do share mysql instance and core files on nfs mount, What happens right now is there is no logic and when second ant call runs dump on the second server it overwrites the previous dump from the first instance with the new data and updated mysql.

So I was thinking on creating a touch task to touch some file since I have shared directory between 2 servers, but I have the same build.xml for both server instances, so the touch will executed on the second ant call and overwrite the modification time of the first ant call.

I thought of if I could share jenkins timestamp property of when job starts within 2 ant jobs. Do not know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance for advise.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use the environment variable `BUILD_NUMBER` set by Jenkins and make it stored on you nfs, as a property file for instance.

So if that property file doesn't exists, or if the value of the property loaded from there doesn't match the environment variable set by Jenkins, it means the current node is the first to run for that Jenkins job. So it can do the backup. And that node would overwrite the shared property file with the current build number.

If the loaded property match the current build number, then it means the first run has already been done, no backup to do.

Implementation hints:

- add the build number to the command line

  ```
  usr/bin/ant -v -d -f /utils_repo/build.xml ${target} -propertyfile /tmp/myjob/install.properties -Dexpected.jenkins.build.number=$BUILD_NUMBER
  ```
- use ant contrib if/then/else tasks: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html
- write the property file with:

  ```
  <echo file="/mnt/nfs/shared/jenkins.properties">jenkins.build.number=$expected.jenkins.build.number</echo>
  ```